# HQL/SQL select top 10 records based on count

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have 2 tables:

```
CATEGORY (id)
POSTING (id, categoryId)
```

I am trying to write an HQL or SQL query to find top 10 Categories which have the most number of Postings.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What are your tries ? Which database you are using ? How have you defined your entities ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL and have not tried anything yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

SQL query:

```
SELECT  c.Id, sub.POSTINGCOUNT
FROM CATEGORY c where c.Id IN
( 
    SELECT TOP 10 p.categoryId
    FROM POSTING p
    GROUP BY p.categoryId 
    order by count(1) desc
)
```

HQL:

```
Session.CreateQuery("select c.Id
        FROM CATEGORY c where c.Id IN
        ( 
            SELECT  p.categoryId
            FROM POSTING p
            GROUP BY p.categoryId 
            order by count(1) desc
        )").SetMaxResults(10).List();
```

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/01/12/in-vs-inner-join/

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can do this:

```
SELECT c.Id, sub.POSTINGCOUNT
FROM CATEGORY c 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT p.categoryId, COUNT(id) AS 'POSTINGCOUNT'
    FROM POSTING p
    GROUP BY p.categoryId
) sub ON c.Id = sub.categoryId
ORDER BY POSTINGCOUNT DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Excellent, I will try that.  Is there an HQL equivalent?  Thank you!

Comment: @user879220, Soryry, I am not familiar with HQL, but I think it will be very similer to the SQL syntax see this page you will find all what you need to write this sql query in HQL http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: I think I can use SQL with Hibernate I will try that.  The only other thing which I found is "Top is not supported in mySQL, you can use SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5 to get the top 5 records "

Comment: @user879220, In mysql use `LIMIT 10` instead of `TOP(10)` see my edit.

Comment: @user879220, In nhibernate you can write sql queries directly against the database with `Session.CreateSQLQuery('you native sql query here')`, but in hibernate I don't know how you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

SQL can be like :

```
SELECT c.* from CATEGORY c, (SELECT count(id) as postings_count,categoryId
FROM POSTING 
GROUP BY categoryId ORDER BY postings_count
LIMIT 10) d where c.id=d.categoryId
```

This output can be mapped to the Category entity.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old question, but i reached a satisfatory answer.

JPQL:

```
//the join clause is necessary, because you cannot use p.category in group by clause directly
@NamedQuery(name="Category.topN", 
     query="select c, count(p.id) as uses 
            from Posting p 
            join p.category c 
            group by c order by uses desc ")
```

Java:

```
List<Object[]> list = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Category.topN", Object[].class)
            .setMaxResults(10)
            .getResultList();
//here we must made a conversion, because the JPA cannot order using a non select field (used stream API, but you can do it in old way)
List<Category> cats = list.stream().map(oa -> (Category) oa[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```